# Using LocalDate in Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to allow the user to input a date of acquisition, however when I put the element into Thymeleaf and try to use it, I get a white label error, along wit the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dateAcquired' of bean class. Bean property 'dateAcquired' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Now normally I would know that I need to put a setter and getter into my Java code in order to get this to work, however, I've got the following in my class:

```
@Column(name = "entry_dateAcquired")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dateAcquired = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));

...

public LocalDate getDateAcquired() { return this.dateAcquired; }

public void setDateAcquired(LocalDate dateAcquired) { this.dateAcquired = dateAcquired; }
```

I'm not 100% sure as to why it's not displaying... When I submit an entry into my database, I can see that the backend is working properly as there is a date entry in the db.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to place annotations `@Column` and ` @DateTimeFormat` on your getter ?

Comment: Is your database column named `entry_dateAcquired` ?

Comment: What would that do? As you can already see that I've got both set on the variable itself when I declare it?